# Why is the ConfigurationManager.GetSection "system.webServer/handlers" not available?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-config, httphandler

I'm trying to read some configuration in my global.aspx `Application_Start` method. When I read `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/httpHandlers")` everything is fine:

> ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/httpHandlers")
>   {System.Web.Configuration.HttpHandlersSection}
>       base {System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection}: {System.Web.Configuration.HttpHandlersSection}
>       Handlers: Count = 48

But when I read `ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.webServer/handlers")` (which contains my custom handlers, it returns `null`. What am I doing wrong?

The section looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.loc" name="LocalizedResourceStreamer" 
                 type="CFW.WebUI.HttpHandlers.LocalizedResourceStreamer,WebUI" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Notes:

- Web.configs are nested, `ConfigurationManager.GetSection` takes nesting into account by default.
- The overall problem is trying to see if *.loc files are being served.

So far:
[image]
Looks like the *system.webServer* is ignored.

Comment: config content would be usefull

Comment: maybe it can help:http://ayende.com/blog/3360/i-hate-iis-today

Comment: Added the config section

Comment: Something smells bad if you're having to read config sections like that (that "belong" to asp.net more than your app)

Comment: Well I need to read if *.loc files are handled. If they aren't handled I would like to throw an error on the application start, so it is not forgotten.

Comment: Interesting thread here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/31827ac7-8ab0-4eba-a37a-33ad19942e62/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your OS/setup, the `system.webServer` element may be configured to be ignored - and so the config system will not be constructing any inner configuration items from it. E.g. on my machine (WinXP, IIS 5.1), it's set to ignored by default.

Check the `machine.config` on the machine where this code is running, and see how the `system.webServer` element is configured. I don't have machines available with suitable later OSes at the moment, but it may be that this element is always set to be ignored - after all, that part of the config is for IIS' use, rather than our own.

Comment: It is true, it is ignored. How can I config it to be taken into account?

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker - I'd seriously suggest changing tack - perhaps whatever you're trying to achieve can be done without having to load that config section yourself? But we don't know what the overall problem is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: The overall problem is trying to see whether my .loc files are being served.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker - the easiest way to be *sure* may be to simply make a request for one - otherwise, even if the handler is registered, you can't be 100% sure that IIS is routing requests for that extension to asp.net, so the handler would be unreachable.

Answer (score 1):

try :

**p.s. my web.config contains :     `<httpHandlers>`  and not `handlers` as yours. change as necessarily :) - also the webserver vs system.web **

[image]

```
   Configuration webConfig = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(Request.ApplicationPath);

        ConfigurationSection webConfigSections = webConfig.GetSection("system.web/httpHandlers");
        if (webConfigSections != null)
        {
         //   PropertyInformationCollection t = webConfigSections.ElementInformation.Properties;

            XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(webConfigSections.SectionInformation.GetRawXml()));
            IEnumerable<XElement> query = from c in xmlFile.Descendants("add") select c;

            foreach (XElement band in query)
            {
            }


        }
```

p.s. thats the problem with this section - he doesnt have a uniquee element name that can be taken. thats why you take it whole("add" element) and parse it.

Comment: I think you mean system.webserver, not system.web

Comment: @ScottE each web.config ( by iis ver) is different. please change it to the one you need. - Ive also added a comment on that. thanks.

Comment: Also... a web.config might be nested, did you take that into account? My handler is actually registered in the "parent" application.

Comment: @RoyiNamir I see what is the difference, I'm creating a class: `namespace CFW.WebUI
{
 public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication` Solution is part of a DLL.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker `might be nested` ?? you should write this ! Im not supposed to guess that. the solution i gave you Does help you read sections from web.config. please re-write your question with additions.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker also give example of the nested web.config so we see the whole picture.

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker if you use the machine config you can use the OpenMachineConfiguration command.

Comment: ConfigurationManager.GetSection takes nesting into account by default

Comment: @KeesC.Bakker so everything is fine. Just use the code I gave you.